# Why is Javascript text editor WidgEditor not submitting any values?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, text-editor

When I click submit and try to get the text from the `textarea`, I am getting blank. I don't know why.

```js
function textSubmit() {
  var text = $("#noise").val();
  console.log(text);
  console.log("here");
  
  var htmlText = $(text);
  console.log(htmlText);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <form>
      <input type="text" id="Title" placeholder="Text Title">
      <br>
      <br>
      <textarea id="noise" name="noise" class="widgEditor nothing"></textarea>
      <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="textSubmit()" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas why? I can't figure it out

im using the following text editor http://www.themaninblue.com/experiment/widgEditor/

i ended up using another text editor, https://github.com/tovic/rich-text-editor
thank you for the help.

Comment: even when using this library, please try just to include `.text()` in your code. If it doesn't wortk I'll delete my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're lacking `.text()` in your code. Take a look:

```js
function textSubmit() {
  var text = $("#noise").val();
  console.log(text);
  console.log("here");
  
  var htmlText = $(text).text();
  console.log(htmlText);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <form>
      <input type="text" id="Title" placeholder="Text Title">
      <br>
      <br>
      <textarea id="noise" name="noise" class="widgEditor nothing"><strong>sajdhas</strong></textarea>
      <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="textSubmit()" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```